# ROR and JS debugging

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've just read through some tutorials on using ajax with rails. Below you can see a JS script extracted from one of them with some modifications which I expected to cause some errors and write some text somewhere. (public/javascripts/application.js)

```
$('.submittable').live('change', function() {
  $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
  fdafdasfewa
  document.write("Welcome to my world!!!");
  echo "------------------";
});
```

In fact the script still works with no side effects.

Where does document.write and echo put text?

How can I debug such a script when I can't even see its output? Well sometimes probably I'll not even be able to determine if ran or not.

Comment: Did you use firebug ? Is very usefull to debug javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting in an alert to make sure your code is being reached

```
$('.submittable').live('change', function() {
  $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
  alert('reached this point');
  ...
```

Also, use Firebug or Chrome's development tools. In Chrome on the mac the shortcut is command-alt-i to bring up the dev tools, then click 'console' to bring up...the console.

In the console you can type

```
$('.submittable')
```

To make sure your js has a dom element to attach to. If `$('.submittable')` returns nothing then there's no dom element selected. You can even set breakpoints and step through them in the dev tools. To create a break point just do

```
$('.submittable').live('change', function() {
  $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
  debugger;
  ...
```

and the dev tools will take over when that line is reached.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is when you called the `$(this).parents('form:first').submit()` the page posted the form and javascript didn't execute past that point, which is why it didn't throw any errors of or write anything to the document.

I would use console.log to write test output in combination with the developer tools in chrome or Firebug.  That way you know to look in the console and you can also use things like breakpoints to watch the execution of the javascript.